# React Caching of Top Level Components

Tags: reactjs, performance, dom

I'm new to React and understand that it re-renders a component if its state or any ancestor's state changes. However, this default behavior of re-rendering all nested components may be suboptimal for performance, especially with deeply nested components. The React documentation suggests using useMemo to cache it's JSX to improve performance.

If the props of a component have not changed, wouldn't it be more efficient for React to skip re-rendering that component and avoid comparing the virtual DOM subtree?"

In other words, instead of re-rendering and comparing the virtual DOM subtree of a component with the previous DOM tree, and based on this determine which DOM updates to apply, React could avoid this process entirely if it determines that the props have not changed. If the props have not changed, the returned JSX will be the same as the previous and so no change in the component's subtree and therefore no updates to the browser DOM. No need to do JSX caching.

Comment: Provided there's  no prop value like this ``myProp = { Math.random() }``, it's guaranteed that if a component's  props have not changed, its JSX and that of all nested components will be the same as in the previous render. So this component's subtree will remain unchanged

Comment: The other exception is components that consume state via context instead of using props. To skip re-rendering the entire subtree of a component whose props have not changed, React would need also to confirm that the nested components are not consuming state via the Context API.